# How to set an additional value to an existing child to Firebase Realtime android kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I need to set value to an existing child. For example:

[image]

I have Users -> profileUid -> phone and uid, but i want to add new value, for example - name, that i have three values: phone, profileUid and name.

I used this code to add "name":

```
private fun setName(name: String) {
    val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    hashMap["name"] = name

    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")

    reference.child(getProfileUid()!!)
        .setValue(hashMap)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Успешно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

But if I do it this way, then all the values ​​are removed and only the name remains, like on this screenshot:

[image]

How can I add a "name" value so that others are not deleted?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only write the child nodes you have in your map, use `updateChildren`:

```
reference.child(getProfileUid()!!)
    .updateChildren(hashMap)
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [updating specific fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

Comment: I have a new question for you man. I am using the firebase real-time database for 2 years but my question is what if I exceed 100 connections in real-time database  and don't cross any other limits then how much i have to pay ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try use `SetOptions.merge()`, this would look like

```
reference.child(getProfileUid()!!)
    .setValue(hashMap, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Успешно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

`merge` takes care of updating the document without replacing existing data, but if you're not sure the document exists, don't use the option to `merge` the new data with any existing document, to avoid overwriting entire documents.